# Taking list of elements as param in Class method

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, class, methods

I have a class `Dbcrud()` that I will outline below.

I want to take several parameters from a method: `db_select()` one being `selected_fields` which would be a list of fields.

Im having trouble forming my method `db_select()` to allow multiple fields to be defined for `selected_fields`.

Can someone help?

Thank you
**UPDATED**

```
class DbCrud:
    query_stmt_list = ['SELECT','INSERT','UPDATE','DELETE','FROM','WHERE']
    def __init__(self):
        self.query_stmt_list = DbCrud.query_stmt_list

    self.query_stmt_list = query_stmt_list

    def set_db_settings(self, host, username, passwd, database):
        self.host = host
        self.username = username
        self.passwd = passwd
        self.database = database
        db = pymysql.connect(host=host, user=username, passwd=passwd, db=database)
        return db
    def db_select(self, selected_fields, table, where_field):
        self.selected_fields = selected_fields
        self.table = table
        self.where_field = where_field
        try:
            with db.cursor() as cursor:
                sql_tld_id_query = self.query_stmt_list[0] + selected_fields* + self.query_stmt_list[4] + table + self.query_stmt_list[5] + where_field + '=' + %s
                cursor.execute(sql_tld_id_query, (self.site_search_url,))
                tld_id_value = cursor.fetchone() 
        except:
            db.rollback()
            pass
```

Comment: You have a syntax issue `selected_fields[]` can't be parameter to a function, you need to call it `selected_fields`, and this parameter can be whatever you like it to be. Also you need to define `self.query_stmt_list = query_stmt_list` in the `__init__` method

Comment: You have a syntax error, you do not indicate the type of variables in any way in Python, unless you use type annotations. It should be `selected_fields` without the trailing `[]`. If you want to show its a list for documentation purposes, you can use `selected_fields: List[Any]`, to do this however you have to add `from typing import List, Any` at the top of your file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have few issues  here:

**1.**
You need that row at the init method (as this is the c'tor of the class)
Also as `query_stmt_list` is a static member, you should access him with the class name as prefix.

```
def __init__(self):    
    self.query_stmt_list = DbCrud.query_stmt_list
```

**2.** 
You can't define a function param with `selected_fields[]`, it's a syntax error, you can pass to `selected_fields` whatever you like.

```
def db_select(self, selected_fields, table, where_field):
```

**3.**
When you try to use the variable `query_stmt_list` (at the following line of code i've attached), do you mean you want the class member or the instance member?

If instance you should change it to `self.query_stmt_list`

If the class member, you should change it to `DbCrud.query_stmt_list`

```
sql_tld_id_query = query_stmt_list[0] + selected_fields* + query_stmt_list[4] + table + query_stmt_list[5] + where_field + '=' + %s
```

Also, in order to loop though the `selected_fields` you could do:

```
query_stmt_list[0] + ", ".join(item for item in self.selected_fields) + query_stmt_list[4] ...
```

Comment: @omri_saadon-  can you see updated? How does this look? Im newer to classes (as evident in the post) and wanted to get your feedback. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You can always expect `selected_fields` to be a list so you can use `', '.join`:

```
def db_select(self, selected_fields, table, where_field):
    query = 'select {selected_fields} {table} where {where_field} = 1'
    query = query.format(selected_fields=', '.join(selected_fields),
                         table=table, where_field=where_field)
    .
    .

obj.db_select(['col_a'], 'table_a', 'where_field_a')
```

Note that this is vulnerable to SQL injection, but so is your original code (if it wasn't for the syntax errors it currently has).